# Missing VM in old portal on the Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-hub

We have created a VM in ARM mode (Azure Resource Manager) that is the new mode available only in the new portal (https://portal.azure.com).

Now we would to do setup for End Point services to do so we need to check using old Azure view Htps://manage.azure.com.

on the https://manage.azure.com we could not see created VM machine on this site. it is showing 0 VM machine but on the Portal page it showing our created VM machine.

Kindly let me us know how to visualise our VM machines on Both of Azure page.

Thanks,

Comment: If you wish to see VMs showing in both old and new portal, you must create them using `Classic` mode. However considering old portal will be deprecated soon and so will be the `Classic` way of doing things, I would not recommended going down that route.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, we have created VM machine using New Portal, Ie. https://portal.azure.com. There is no possibility to see the same using classic portal?

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to view the Resource manager VM in old classic portal. You can view it only in new portal. As Azure will gradually move towards using only the new portal, they stopped adding new functionalities in old portal and allow them only in new portal. Resource manager is one such functionality. However all the VMs in classic portal will be visible in New portal and you can configure everything in new portal (including the endpoint creation). There are still some functionalities which depend on old portal still (Like AD, remote App) and they may migrate to new portal in some time, but apart from that New portal is feature rich than the classic portal

Comment: Thanks Sateesh, I too believe so... Thanks for your confirmation

Comment: Thanks, can you mark as answer if it solves your confusion?